# where location to assign function pointer point to a function

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have a `funtion_ptr` function pointer which point to `add_int` function.

case 1: when lay a statement `function_ptr = &add_int` outside `main` function 
--> `compiler error: error C2373: 'function_ptr' : redefinition; different type modifiers` (this is in )

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add_int(int n, int m){
    return n + m;
}
int(*function_ptr)(int, int);
function_ptr = &add_int;  // it's here

void main(){
    int sum = (* function_ptr)(2, 3);
    printf("sum = %d", sum);
    _getch();
}
```

case 2: `function_ptr = &add_int;` in `main` function --> it is true

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add_int(int n, int m){
    return n + m;
}
int(*function_ptr)(int, int);


void main(){
    function_ptr = &add_int;  // it's now here
    int sum = (* function_ptr)(2, 3);
    printf("sum = %d", sum);
    _getch();
}
```

Could anyone explain for me different between the two case.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function_ptr = &add_int;` is an assignment statement. Statements are allowed inside functions, but outside functions only declarations are allowed. Since assignment is not a declaration, the compiler issues an error.

If you want to assign the pointer as part of its declaration/definition, you could combine the declaration and the assignment, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add_int(int n, int m){
    return n + m;
}
int(*function_ptr)(int, int) = &add_int;

int main(){
    int sum = (* function_ptr)(2, 3);
    printf("sum = %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/W0o7Mo)

Comment: @Next You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer by checking the grey check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the & in the assignment statement, the function's name (add_int) IS its address... and the assignment statement should be within the bounds of a function.

Here's an example that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add_int(int n, int m);

int(*function_ptr)(int, int);


void main(){

    function_ptr = add_int;
    int sum = (* function_ptr)(2, 3);
    printf("sum = %d", sum);
    getc(stdin);
}

int add_int(int n, int m){
    return n + m;
}
```